# Convergence in Distribution which places mass of 1/2 at -1 and +1

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $\{X_{n}\}$ be i.i.d. with $P(X_{n}=1)=P(X_{n}=-1)=1/2$ and let $Y_{n}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{1}{2^{k}}X_{k}}$. Then how do we show that $Y_{n}\rightarrow{U(-1,1)}$ in distribution.

As a solution I tried the following I could not get it ultimately. I used convergence in distribution if and only if convergence in characteristic function.

The characteristic function of $Y\sim{U(-1,1)}$ is $\phi_{Y}(t)=\frac{sin(t)}{t}$ and I found  $\phi_{Y_{n}}(t)=\prod_{k=1}^{n}{cos(\frac{t}{2^{k}})}$. But then I don't see that  $\phi_{Y_{n}}(t)\rightarrow{\phi_{Y}(t)}$ as $n\rightarrow{\infty}$ for all $t$.

Comment: It is easier if you think about $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{X_k}{2^k}$ and what each coin flip means in terms of where the sum lands.  The first coin flip is negative iff the entire sum is $\leq 0$ for example.  If you repeat this type of argument for each flip, you can see that the limit is uniform on $[-1,1]$.

Comment: @ Chris Janjigian: Yes I understand your arguments. But how do we give the rigorous proof.

Comment: You can figure out what the distribution function is from those arguments.  Try doing it explicitly for $Y_2$ and $Y_3$ if you are having trouble seeing the argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it in the following way:

$\phi_{Y_{n}}(t)=\prod_{k=1}^{n}{cos(\frac{t}{2^{k}})}=\prod_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{2sin(\frac{t}{2^{k}}) cos(\frac{t}{2^{k}})}{2sin(\frac{t}{2^{k}})}}=\frac{sin(t)}{2^{n}sin(\frac{t}{2^{n}})}=sin(t)\frac{\frac{1}{2^{n}}}{sin(\frac{t}{2^{n}})}\rightarrow{\frac{sin(t)}{t}}$ as $n\rightarrow{\infty}$ by L'Hopital rule with respect to $n$.

Answer (score 0):

Why not complete the OP's proof? Let $u_0(t)=1$ and, for every $n\geqslant1$,
$$u_n(t)=\prod\limits_{k=1}^n\cos(t/2^k).
$$
The goal is to prove that $u_n(t)\to v(t)$ for every $t$. Using the doubling formula $\sin(2a)=2\sin a\cos a$ for $a=t/2^n$, one gets
$$
2\sin(t/2^n)u_n(t)=\sin(t/2^{n-1})u_{n-1}(t).
$$
Iterating this yields
$$
u_n(t)=\frac{\sin t}{2^n\sin(t/2^n)},
$$
from which the pointwise convergence of $u_n$ to $\varphi_Y$ is clear.